# Ext 4 History init() thows JS error

Tags: extjs

I'm using Ext 4.0.7
When I try to initialise Ext History as follows:

```
Ext.require(['Ext.util.History']);

Ext.onReady(function(){  

   Ext.util.History.init();

});
```

I get:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null ext-all-debug.js:89797
    Ext.define.startUp ext-all-debug.js:89797
    Ext.define.init ext-all-debug.js:89858
(anonymous function) dashboard.js:5
(anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:10122
call ext-all-debug.js:10078

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before 4.1x you had to have a hidden form in your DOM to allow it to work properly.
My suggestion is to upgrade to 4.1x or add an initialize routine to call before init() as follows:

```
 initialiseHistory: function () {
 this.historyForm = Ext.getBody().createChild({
 tag:    'form',
 action: '#',
 cls:    'x-hidden',
 id:     'history-form',
 children: [
 {
 tag: 'div',
 children: [
 {
 tag:  'input',
 id:   Ext.util.History.fieldId,
 type: 'hidden'
 },
 {
 tag:  'iframe',
 id:   Ext.util.History.iframeId
 }
 ]
 }
 ]
 });
 }
```